# How to do a >= with type checking in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I'm new to PHP and I didn't find a way to compare two element without type Coercion

For example:

```
var_dump(5>="1") // true
var_dump(5>="6") // false
```

Is there an operator that that do it with type check? (I know I could also check if the type is equal I'm just asking if there is a special operator for this)

Comment: Yes you need to check the type separately. `<`/`>` does just tell you if one thing is more or less than the other thing.

Comment: No, there's no `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=` equivalent to `===`; you need to use separate checks for type and value

Comment: just check separately `$varToTest = "5";
var_dump(5>=$varToTest && is_int($varToTest));`

Comment: How would you imagine the boolean result of a strongly typed comparison between integers and strings? Are string-numbers supposed to be "smaller" than integers?

Comment: @Ahmad "Thanks, Hi" is just noise and you should remove it when you're  already editing the post :), see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I will do it from now on.

Comment: @0x13a@MarkBaker @Rizier123 thanks for the answer

Comment: @mario I will except a false as this is clearly not "greater than **and** the same type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are many great answers in the comments, there are more things you can do:

Type juggling:

`var_dump(5>=(int)"1")` will cast `"1"` to an integer (`1`) type.

Type comparison:

```
var_dump(gettype(5) == gettype("1") && 5 >= "1") // false
var_dump(gettype(5) == gettype((int) "1") && 5 >= (int)"1") // true
```

But the short answer is no, there is no short-hand operator to do this as PHP is practically build around the `mix` variable type.

In php 7 you can also use scalar types in functions:
`function foo(integer $bar){}` enabling `strict types` and passing a string to this function will halt script execution.